# Quotient by power of maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring (but see the edit portion below) and $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ such that $|R/\mathfrak{m}|<\infty$. Also assume that $k$ a positive integer. Is it true that for a prime number $p$, we have $p$ dividing $|R/\mathfrak{m}^k|$ if and only if $p$ is the characteristic of the field $R/\mathfrak{m}$?

**Attempt:** One direction is clear because I know (by $0\to\mathfrak{m}^{i-1}/\mathfrak{m}^i\to R/\mathfrak{m}^i\to R/\mathfrak{m}^{i-1}$ repeatedly) that

$$|R/\mathfrak{m}^k|=|R/\mathfrak{m}|\cdot|\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2|\dots|\mathfrak{m}^{k-1}/\mathfrak{m}^k|$$
so if $p$ is the characteristic of $R/\mathfrak{m}$, then $p$ divides $|R/\mathfrak{m}|$ (the additive order of $1$ is $p$ which divides the order of the additive group) and hence divides $|R/\mathfrak{m}^k|$.

However, I am not too sure about the other direction. Specifically, it could be that $p$ divides $|R/\mathfrak{m}^k|$ but the fatcor of $p$ shows up in the $|\mathfrak{m}^{i-1}/\mathfrak{m}^i|$ factors rather than $|R/\mathfrak{m}|$.

**Edit:** I guess I should be clear that in my original context for this question, $R$ is actually the ring of integers $O_K$ for some number field $K$ (finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$). This might affect the analysis (e.g. so $R$ is a Dedekind domain, and also we know $|R/I|<\infty$ for all ideals $I$).

Comment: The order of a finite field is always a power of a prime.  Isn't that all you need for the converse?

Comment: @GregoryGrant But $R/\mathfrak{m}^k$ is not a field...!

Comment: Maybe you want $\mathfrak m$ finitely generated, otherwise I doubt that $R/\mathfrak m^k$ is finite.

Comment: Oh yeah, I think in my original context (see the edit portion), that is true. Because $R$ is Noetherian. And also in my original context, we know $|R/I|<\infty$ for all ideals $I$.

Comment: Then $\mathfrak m^{i-1}/\mathfrak m^i$ is an $R/\mathfrak m$-vector space, so isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $R/\mathfrak m$.

Comment: oh I see! So therefore all the $|\mathfrak{m}^{i-1}/\mathfrak{m}^i|$ must be power of $|R/\mathfrak{m}|$?

Comment: That's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $$|R/\mathfrak{m}^k|=|R/\mathfrak{m}|\cdot|\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2|\cdots|\mathfrak{m}^{k-1}/\mathfrak{m}^k|$$ and use that $\mathfrak m^{i-1}/\mathfrak m^i$ is an $R/\mathfrak m$-vector space, so isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $R/\mathfrak m$.